# add items to a dictionary and save it to a txt file

Tags: python, dictionary, python-3.4

a few weeks ago I have started learning python.

Now I have started to create a program to create a dictionary, add an item1 as a string, add an item2 which consists of numbers and save it after that. But it is not working the way I want it to. It seems like the saving is not working properly it seems to be overwriting the existing items.

Before posting this, I have thoroughly searched here on Stack Overflow to find a solution, but I can't get it to work.

Here is my code:

```
import pickle
import os


if not os.path.exists( 'C:\path' ):  
    os.makedirs( 'C:\path' )        

dict = {}
dict = pickle.load( open( "dict.txt", "rb" ) )

def add_dict(item):

    for item in dict:

        if not item in dict:
            dict.update({item1 : item2})
            print ("thx")
            print (dict)
            print ("added")
        
        if item in dict:
            print("item already exists.")

        return

    return



item1 = input("insert Item1: ")
item1 = item1.lower()
item2 = input("insert item2: ")


pickle.dump(dict, open("C:\path\dict.txt", "wb"))
```

I hope this is not a too specific case.

edit: I have edited my code, to make it less specific and made two mistakes which are fixed now.

```
import pickle
import os

if not os.path.exists( 'C:\path' ):
    os.makedirs( 'C:\path' )

dict = {}
item1 = input('insert item1 ')
item1 = buch.lower()
item2 = input('insert item2: ')
dict.update({item1: item2})
print("thx")
print(dict)
print("added")
pickle.dump(dict, open("C:\path\dict.txt", "wb"))
```

this was the code without the function.

Comment: Could you post a runnable example please. `isbn_liste` is not defined anywhere and `add_dict` is never called. That code is just trash.

Comment: `it seems to be overwriting the existing items` do you mean existing items in text file ?

Comment: You define add_dict(n) but it is not used. In addition the two if `if item in dict` and `if not item in dict`are superfluous since they are in `for item in dict` loop.

Comment: see this https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: @Matthias isbn_liste was something from my unedited code, i have fixed it now. 

I had some different code without a function in it, i will add that one as well.

Comment: @mohaned yes when i check the txt file with another script i wrote, it only prints the items i added previously.

Comment: @lokiderhase I don't understand the question , but if you write data to your text file then when you write another data (it overwrites previous data) it's because the way you open the text file , `open("C:\path\dict.txt", "wb")` if you want to append `open("C:\path\dict.txt", "a")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The edited code still has errors.

I rewrote the whole thing to be more pythonic.

```
import os
import pickle


def read_data(filename):
    try:
        return pickle.load(open(filename, 'rb'))
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return {}


def write_data(filename, data):
    try:
        os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(filename))
    except FileExistsError:
        pass
    pickle.dump(data, open(filename, 'wb'))


def main():
    filename = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'dict.txt')
    data = read_data(filename)

    key = input('insert item1 ').lower()
    value = input('insert item2: ')
    data[key] = value
    print(data)

    write_data(filename, data)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I used meaningful names and didn't call a variable `dict` because [dict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-dict) is a builtin you don't want to overwrite.

First we read the file. If it doesn't exist we catch the error and use an empty dictionary for the data.

Second we get the new data and update the dictionary.

Last we write the dictionary back to disk and create the target folder if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much, i am not too familiar yet with python so i was bound to make mistakes. I didnt run into errors when compiling, so i thought i was doing fine. The naming the dictionary dict was stupid, but it was just made up for posting here. Anyways, thank you for the fast response, i will try it right away! Can i post you my code later on, since i dont know anybody else who is familiar with python and i am pretty sure that i will make mistakes later on.

Comment: It worked, i made the variables and functions more meaningfull to me, and after reading up on how to use the os.path properly, i think i understand how i can use this in the future. Thank you again, i was very frustrated, when it didnt work the way i wanted.